# Open pdf files in Unity

Tags: pdf, unity-game-engine

there is any tool or plugin for Unity that can open PDF files inside the game. I none of these exist, maybe there is tool that can automatically convert PDF files to images.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can open a file with

```
Application.OpenURL("file:///c:/filename.PDF");
```

but if you want to show it on the game window then it is a bit more trickier. Nevertheless here is some good discussion about it: http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/71964-PDF-reader